# $G$ is a subgroup of the group of invertible elements of $\mathcal{A}[G]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

let $G$ be a group and let $\mathcal{A}[G]$ be the group algebra of $G$.

I want to show the statement from the book "$G$ is a subgroup of the group of invertible elements of $\mathcal{A}[G]$."

So first I want to determine which elements are invertible:

$$(\sum_{g\in G} x(g)\delta_g)*(\sum_{h\in G}y(h)\delta_h)=\sum_{g,h\in G}x(g)y(h)\delta_{gh}=\delta_e$$

So all terms where $gh\ne e$ vanish $\implies$
$$=\sum_{gh=e} x(g)y(h)\delta_e$$
$$\implies \sum_{gh=e}x(g)y(h)=1$$
$$\implies \sum_{g\in G}x(g)y(g^{-1})=1$$

I am not sure how to get from here to the statement. For one thing, I can't see in what way $G$ can be a subgroup of $\mathcal{A}[G]$. I imagine they mean an isomorphic copy of $G$ or something?

Comment: If you think of $\mathcal{A}[G]$ as formal linear combinations of elements of $G$, that already makes $G$ a subset of $\mathcal{A}[G],$ and the multiplication operation in $\mathcal{A}[G]$ restricted to the subset $G$ is simply the usual group operation.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you prove that $G$, interpreted as a subset of $\mathcal{A}[G]$, is *contained* in the set of invertible elements.

Don't try to prove the other way round (as you did) since you won't be lucky (see e.g. Kaplansky'S conjectures). (as you wrote *group algebra* I assume you mean that $\mathcal{A}$ is a field) It is simply not true that the invertible elements of $\mathcal{A}[G]$ "look" exactly like the elements of $G$. Think of "multiples" of elements of $G$ for example (again see Kaplansky's conjectures).

So write down an element of $G$ in its "shape" as an element of $\mathcal{A}[G]$ and try to find its inverse in $\mathcal{A}[G]$. I guess you will see that this is not a hard task.

Comment: I think if $\mathcal{A}=\mathbb{F}_2$, and if $G$ is abelian and torsion-free, then $(\mathcal{A}[G])^{\times}\simeq G$ (I saw it in a paper, I can guve references if necessary); but it won't be the case more generally